# How to fix date format when converting a text file into excel?

Tags: excel, vba, xls

I use `amacro` to convert txt files into `xls` but I have the problem that the fields with dates are not converting in the right format. For example I have the date `4/11/2014` `(dd/mm/yyyy)` and when the file is converted into `xls`, I have the date shown like this `:11/4/2014.`

How can I fix it?

code:

```
Public Sub Read_TXT()
Dim Dir_p As String, File_to_Open As String
Dir_p = ActiveWorkbook.path
File_to_Open = Dir(Dir_p & "\")
While File_to_Open <> ""
  If InStr(1, Right(File_to_Open, 3), "txt", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Dir_p & "\" & File_to_Open, _
        Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Dir_p & "\" & Left(File_to_Open, Len(File_to_Open) - 3) & "xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
  End If
  File_to_Open = Dir
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: can you post the code that you are using? It will need a slight modification to force the date format.

Comment: i post it . thank you

Comment: Which column are the dates going into when this has been run?

Comment: columns: E,H,S,V,AB,AF,AJ,AL,AO,AS,AY,BE,BH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two methods that you can use here, the short way - which doesn't always work - or the long way, which will work, but will take a while to run.

The short way:

```
Columns("E, H, S, V, AB, AF, AJ, AL, AO, AS, AY, BE, BH").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

The long way:

```
Dim bigRange As Range, rCell As Range

'// If your data has headers, change the 1 to a 2 in all the lines below.

Set bigRange = Union(Range("E1", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("H1", Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("S1", Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("V1", Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("AB1", Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("AF1", Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("AJ1", Range("AJ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("AL1", Range("AL" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("AO1", Range("AO" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("AS1", Range("AS" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("AY1", Range("AY" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("BE1", Range("BE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
    Range("BH1", Range("BH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))

For Each rCell In bigRange.Cells
    With rCell
         .Value = Format(CDate(.Value2), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End With
Next rCell
```

Comment: i will add this in my code (Read_TXT) OR use it in new Sub ?

Comment: You could technically do either, but if you're not that familiar with VBA I would advise running this as a separate procedure after the `Read_TXT()` sub

Comment: in any way it seems that it doesn't change the format but it understand it in the wrong way. ex. date 4/11/2014, after convertion will shown as 11/4/2014 BUT date 28/11/2014 will be shown right as 28/11/2014.

Comment: Yes, this is because Excel is trying to read it as an American date format. If the day is 01 - 12 it will assume this is a month instead, and use the mm/dd/yyyy format. If the day is greater than 12, then it clearly isn't a month and Excel will assume the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: Excel saves dates as a Double data type, and so the code above reads this coded value, and then forces it do be displayed in the preferred date format of "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: it stops at this point --> .Value = Format(CDate(.Value2), "dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: I added a comment in the post about headers, if your data has headers you will need to change `1` to `2` on each line of the `Union()` function.

Comment: If I want to use the first-easy method, where should I post it in my code?

Comment: Before the line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ...` Be aware though that the easy method probably won't work due to the way the text is being read by Excel.